# Interpreting this piece of JavaScript

Tags: regex

I'd like to understand what this line of JavaScript means...

```
(/^\w+, ?\w+, ?\w\.?$/)
```

i understand 'w stands for 'word', but need your help in understanding `'/', '^', '+', '?', '.?$/'`

Thank you..

Comment: In what context does HTML do regular expressions?

Comment: **If** that is HTML, then it means the string `(/^\w+, ?\w+, ?\w\.?$/)`.  HTML is markup though as opposed to code; chances are you're looking at Javascript.

Comment: @Andrzej With that much reputation, you could help us turn this question into a better one. My hands are tied.

Comment: yes, it is javascript. sorry for the mistake.

Comment: @pestaa - I don't like to actually *rewrite* peoples' questions (formatting/spelling/grammar is fine), unless they're actively *bad* yet get excellent answers regardless.  Additionally, there's an irony that they ones that need rewriting the most are often the ones that are impossible to work out what the questioner was trying to say.  (Not this one, though.)

Answer (score 2):

That's a [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression), not HTML.

It's inside of a regex literal (`/.../`) in Javascript.

- `^` matches the beginning of the string
- `\w` matches any word character
- `+` matches one or more of the previous set.
- `?` matches zero or one of the previous set (in this case a single space)
- `\.` matches a `.`.  (An unescaped `.` matches any single character)
- `$` matches the end of the string.

Comment: Note that using `\w` for a “word’ character will (under many circumstance) mean any one character which **either** has the Letter property, **or** which has the Decimal Number property, **or** which is the LOW LINE (ie, underscore) character.  Additionally, `^` and `$` can sometimes match next to line boundaries not just string boundaries.

Answer (score 2):

Let's break it down, because then it is easier to read:

```
^        beginning of the line
\w+      1 or more 'word' characters
,        a comma
 ?       an optional space
\w+      1 or more 'word' characters
,        a comma
 ?       an optional space
\w       a single 'word' character
\.?      an optional period
$        end of line
```

The meaning of a 'word' character is an alpha-numeric character or an underscore.

Comment: Note that there are 15,104 code points that count as `\w`, because `ˋunichars ‑‑⁠bmp ‑‑⁠astral '\w' | wc -lˋ == 15104`.

Comment: thanks tchrist...i did not understand 'unichars ‑‑⁠bmp ‑‑⁠astral '\w' | wc -lˋ == 15104' though..could you elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

It is ***not HTML*** code but **Regular Expression**. Read more about it:

- [Regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)

---

> In computing, regular expressions,
>   also referred to as regex or regexp,
>   provide a concise and flexible means
>   for matching strings of text, such as
>   particular characters, words, or
>   patterns of characters. A regular
>   expression is written in a formal
>   language that can be interpreted by a
>   regular expression processor, a
>   program that either serves as a parser
>   generator or examines text and
>   identifies parts that match the
>   provided specification.

Answer (score 1):

`/^\w+, ?\w+, ?\w\.?$/`

Outside in...

- `/ /` delimiters
- `^ $` Matches the whole string (`^` means to match the beginning, `$` means to match the end)

One by one...

- `\w` means word character (simply `w` doesn't match anything but the ASCII character `w`)
- `\w+` word characters (at least one, matches as much as possible)
- `?` means the spaces are optional, matches 0 or 1 space character
- `.` matches any character that is not a line break (can be configured with regex modifiers)
- `\.` (like in the example) matches exactly one dot

Comment: Don’t just say “word”; explain that it’s `[_\pL\p{Nd}]`. Usually `.` doesn’t match any character, but just non-newlines. Sometimes it matches anything at all, and sometimes it matches anything that isn’t a `\R`.  But there is no unescaped `.` in the pattern as posted.

Comment: @tchrist Improved the answer, thanks for the feedback. I intentionally introduced `.` and `\.` separately, and emphasized the presence of the latter only. For a newbie, the difference might not be straightforward.

Comment: thank you. how would an actual expression look like that matches these criteria, particularly the section '?\w\.?'

Comment: @tchrist...thanks for the . and \. explanation, indeed i'm a newbie and they both made things clearer.

Comment: @Roy '\w\.?' would match 'A', 'b.' and the like. You may not want to start an expression with the question mark.

Answer (score 1):

It's a regular expression that looks for a string of word characters (like letters, digits, or underscores) that has two commas in it with an optional single space after each comma.